# user-data shell is not executed when an EC2 instance launched by ASG/Launch Configuration with custom AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I have a set of Auto scaling group and launch configuration to manage certain EC2 instances.
After changing the AMI to a **custom AMI**, the **user data script** that I set in the launch configuration **is not executed** at the instance startup time. (*This Custom AMI is built with [Packer](https://www.packer.io/plugins/builders/amazon)*)

The user data I've set in the launch configuration is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install -y git
```

If I connect the instance via ssh, then I can see an **unknown cloud-init directives** in the `/var/lib/cloud/instance/user-data.txt` path as below:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - [sh, -c, "mkdir /home/company/.ssh"]
 - [sh, -c, "echo 'ssh-rsa ... > /home/company/.ssh/authorized_keys"]
 - [sh, -c, "chmod 0600 /home/company/.ssh/authorized_keys"]
 - [sh, -c, "chown -R company:company /home/company/.ssh"]
```

What I have tried to are :

1. Added `#cloud-boothook` at the top of user data -> Doesn't work
2. Asked a person who created the custom AMI and he/she said they cannot solve this issue because if they test by themselves with the user data, it works fine in AWS Console EC2 launch menu.

Is there any approach to handle this issue?

Comment: First thought, Have you removed whatever is there in `/var/lib/cloud/` from the custom ami and try again?

Comment: Actually, I don’t understand how can I remove the files before the instance is started up. Do you mean  creating a new ami with empty ‘/var/lib/cloud/‘ directory? Or is there any way to remove data before the new instance is created from the ami? The custom ami is not configurable because it’s made from others. @Riz

Comment: Are you running `cloud-init clean` as part of your packer script? If not, cloud-init is likely not detecting your launch as the first boot. Most cloud-init modules only run on first boot.